# How to select model when different models are preferred with different seeds?

Tags: model-selection, references, lasso, ridge-regression, randomness

I am trying to apply the lasso or ridge regression to my data set for the feature selection, *but different random seeds produce different models*. What is a good or universal way to obtain the final model?

- Fix a seed, OR
- combine models from different seeds (if so, then how should I combine them?), OR
- compare models from several different seeds and find a kind of representative model?

Any comments or references will be really appreciated!

Comment: +1 for a great question. My 1st guess is that neither model is really better than the other--there is some ambiguity given your data. If you want predictions, you could try model averaging.

Comment: I have to turn it round. Why do you think a trustable final model exists if results depend on seed choice?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am working on the prediction of survival. Once I set up the final model, I need to validate this model in an independent data set. But I guess that different models (with different seeds) can lead to different results. So I wonder there is a commonly used way to determine a final model... Regarding model averaging, I thought that it could be used when I want to combine models with different "methods" (not  models with different seeds). I should do some research.